# Multiple Schema Permissions In SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We are migrating a database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 R2 and have run into a problem with our schemas. In SQL Server 2000, if you didn't prefix your object names with a owner/schema (e.g. `SELECT * FROM blah` rather than `dbo.blah`) SQL Server would still figure it out. This worked even if your object was in a non-dbo owner.

In SQL Server 2005 this was changed as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mssqlisv/archive/2007/03/23/upgrading-to-sql-server-2005-and-default-schema-setting.aspx.

I can get around a database having 2 schemas by making a user's default schema xyz instead of dbo. The problem I run into is in a database where there is a 3rd schema (abc.blah). When I make the users default xyz, they can get to dbo without a hitch but get an Invalid Object error when trying to select something from abc without a schema prefix (abc.blah works fine).

Of course, it shouldn't have been coded this way to begin with but that is a different battle. I've verified that permissions are not an issue.

I'm sure others have run into this. Has anyone found a workaround other than fixing the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a whole lot of magic here; fix the code.

Assuming you don't have same-named objects in both schemas, you may be able to create a slew of synonyms like:

```
CREATE SYNONYM xyz.foo FOR dbo.foo;
```

...but that is going to be as much of a mess as fixing the code.

Comment: Thanks Aaron...pretty much what I expected. I've noticed that my workaround for 2 schemas works for SQL Users but not for NT users. Any idea why that would be the case?

Comment: I think there is a problem with default schema and win auth that has been fixed in SQL Server 2012 (memory is fuzzy and I am too lazy to search)